# Operators and precedence in c

Tags: c, pointers, operators, operator-precedence

I came across the following program.

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
    int main() 
    { 
      char *s[] = { "knowledge","is","power"}; 
      char **p; 
      p = s; 
      printf("%s ", ++*p); 
      printf("%s ", *p++); 
      printf("%s ", ++*p); 

      return 0; 
    }
```

Output: `nowledge nowledge s`
I'm sure
1.First printf prints `nowledge`
2.Second printf also prints `nowledge` because it contains a post increment so original value of first printf is retained.
Now at this stage I'm confused what exactly *p++ does. Now will p to point to `is` or `owledge`.

Comment: I know the output.. but i wanna know the explanation - @ralph

Comment: Why don't you read some documentation on operator precedence? You should learn how to do that so that you can reason about code.

Comment: @ralph You don't learn this by trial and error!

Comment: For instance, you could read this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output of this program is quite confusing because `++*p` increments the value pointed to by `p` which makes different elements of the string array `s` to get incremented.

```
  printf("%s ", ++*p);
```

The value returned by `*p` gets incremented. `p` points to `s[0]`. Therefore will `s[0]` point to `"nowledge"`.

```
  printf("%s ", *p++);
```

`p` still points to the first element of the `char *` array. Because we incremented the value of `s[0]` by one previously will `s[0]` still point to `"nowledge"`. `p` gets incremented after the dereference.

```
  printf("%s ", ++*p);
```

The value returned by `*p` gets incremented. `s[1]` will get incremented and point to `"s"`.

Answer (score 0):

The value at *p is of type *char 
(the value of a pointer being an address that is allocated the size of the type it is pointing to)

incrementing it would result in that value being added a sizeof(char)

It's like writing this :

```
  printf("%s ", ++(*p));
```

The value at p is of type **char

incrementing it would result in that value added a typeof(*char)  .

the difference is that the value in the next address holding a *char 
is the address of the first char in of the next char array

I didn't look at the precedence sheet (which i'm sure you can find in simple google search)
but from running the code you can understand that ++ precedes *

if you want to check it out run this :

```
 printf("%s ", (*p)++);
```

Comment: Yes but when i'm incrementing p why is it jumping to 'is' while in above two printf's it is incrementing character by character. In first printf 'K' was omitted.  So why after second printf cursor jumped to next string 'is'.

Answer (score 0):

```
  char *s[] = { "knowledge","is","power"}; // s is an array of pointers
  char **p; // p is a pointer to a pointer to char
  p = s; 
  printf("%s ", ++*p); //(*p) pointing to first string of s, pre-increment so "nowledge" printed
  printf("%s ", *p++); // (*p) printed then post-increment  of p (not *p) hence jumped to next pointer in the array s
  printf("%s ", ++*p);
```